# What is the problem with my Python3 script's parsing of non-ASCII UTF-8 arguments under Linux?

Tags: python, linux, macos, unicode, utf-8

Consider this trivial Python3 script, which simply prints out the contents of `sys.argv`, both as-is and encoded into UTF-8:

```
import locale
import sys

print("filesystem encoding is:      ", sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print("local preferred encoding is: ", locale.getpreferredencoding())

print("sys.argv is:")
print(sys.argv)

for a in sys.argv:
   print("Next arg is: ", a)
   print("UTF-8 encoding of arg is: ", a.encode())
```

If I run this script (via Python 3.11.4) on my Mac (OSX/Ventura 13.3.1/Intel), with an argument that includes [a non-ASCII UTF-8 character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), I get the expected results:

```
$ python /tmp/supportfiles/test.py Joe’s
filesystem encoding is:       utf-8
local preferred encoding is:  UTF-8
sys.argv is:
['./test.py', 'Joe’s']
Next arg is:  ./test.py
UTF-8 encoding of arg is:  b'./test.py'
Next arg is:  Joe’s
UTF-8 encoding of arg is:  b'Joe\xe2\x80\x99s'
```

However, if I run the same command with the same arguments under Linux (Ubuntu 3.19.0, Linux, Python 3.7.0), things go wrong and the script throws a `UnicodeEncodeError` exception:

```
filesystem encoding is:       utf-8         
local preferred encoding is:  UTF-8         
sys.argv is:        
['./test.py', 'Joe\udce2\udc80\udc99s']
Next arg is:  ./test.py
UTF-8 encoding of arg is:  b'./test.py'
Next arg is:  Joe’s         
Traceback (most recent call last):          
  File "./test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("UTF-8 encoding of arg is: ", a.encode())         
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: surrogates not allowed
```

My question is, is this a bug in Python or in my Linux box's localization environment, or am I doing something wrong?

And, is there anything I can to do get my script to correctly handle command line arguments containing non-ASCII characters on all OS's?

Comment: Like the error says, you're somehow passing it a character encoded in UTF-16 surrogate pair codepoints that shouldn't be used in UTF-8 (There should only be 2, but you have 3, so it's even more broken). How are you generating the argument to your script?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Getting the same result on Linux as you are getting on your Mac. `\udce2\udc80\udc99` looks very suspicious. These characters are low surrogates. How do you invoke the python command? Do you type it in a terminal or run from a script?

Comment: Can you run commands `locale` and `python -V` on both systems and post results ?

Comment: @jeremy-friesner, assuming Python 3.7 onwards: what does the `locale` command report as the system locale? Is the `PYTHONUTF8` environment variable set? Is utf8_mode set? Use the command `sys.flags.utf8_mode`. `sys.getfilesystemencoding` will report UTF-8 if utf8_mode is set, regardless of the actual encoding. `sys.argv` uses “surrogateescape” error handler, that would explain the presence of the low surrogates. Also is `PYTHONIOENCODING ` set and what value does it have, if set?

Comment: @Andj Entering `locale` into the shell yields:  `-sh: locale: command not found`.  Entering `print(sys.flags.utf8_mode)` into the Python interpreter prints `1`.  Neither `PYTHONUTF8` nor `PYTHONIOENCODING` appear to be set as environment variables (btw I tried manually setting them both, before running the python test, and that didn't seem to change its behavior at all)

Comment: I suspect that the Python installed on the Linux box isn't configured correctly (it's v3.7.0, and it was built via cross-compilation, so that might be a factor).  For now I've worked around the problem by having my python script check its `sys.argv` values for surrogates, and if it finds them, it converts those bytes back into the UTF-8 chars that they should have been originally, before using them.

Comment: I suspect your system locale isn't a UTF-8 based locale, maybe set to the C locale, or something else. It appears your python install is in utf8_mode, so is reporting utf-8 as the system locale. sys.argv will convert any non-utf-8 sequence into low surrogates.

Comment: what distro are you using?

Comment: It's a Yocto-based embedded distribution; it doesn't include Python in the distribution so we compile Python ourselves.

Comment: It appears to be a distro that uses musl libc. My favourite quote on the musl libc wiki: "Locale support is very limited, and barely works." I suspect you are using the C locale.

Comment: @Andj I suspect you are correct, Python's protestations that it is in UTF-8 mode notwithstanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer to my question is basically that my embedded Linux environment doesn't handle internationalization properly.

For posterity's sake, below is the workaround code I inserted into my Python script to "repair" the malformed `sys.argv` strings into proper UTF-8 that the Python encoder will accept:

```
def IsSurrogateMarker(ordVal):
   highByte = (ordVal & 0xFF00) >> 8
   return ((highByte >= 0xD8) and (highByte <= 0xDF))

# Nasty hack work-around for embedded Linux OS
# mis-encoding UTF-8 argv strings with surrogate bytes
def FixBuggyString(s):
   pendingBytes = []
   r = ''
   for c in s:
      ordVal = ord(c)
      if (IsSurrogateMarker(ordVal)):
         pendingBytes.append(ordVal & 0xFF)  # strip the bogus surrogate-marker
      elif (len(pendingBytes) > 0):
         r += bytearray(pendingBytes).decode()
         pendingBytes = []
         r += c
      else:
         r += c
   if (len(pendingBytes) > 0):
      r = r + bytearray(pendingBytes).decode()
   return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Work-around for buggy UTF-8 in argv strings 
    for i in range(0, len(sys.argv)):
       sys.argv[i] = self.FixBuggyString(sys.argv[i])

    [... remainder of program goes here...]
```